# Azure DevOps Rest API Authentication

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-automation

I am looking to get some advice on how best to authenticate my script with Azure DevOps. I have a PowerShell script that will be running in a Azure Automation Account that uses a Service Principal. Currently I am authenticating my script by creating an account in Azure DevOps and then generating a token.

But I would like to use the Service Principal of the Azure Automation account to authenticate and access the DevOps API using a JWT token. Is this possible?

( When I go to the SPN in Azure AD and look at the API settings that the SPN can access, I do see an option for azure DevOps. Is there a way to leverage this setting in my script)

Comment: don't think it's possible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops